# I have a bool array with uncertain number of digits, how to convert it into a short array, each bool value is a bit

Tags: c#

Because the length of the `bool array` is uncertain, how can I change it?

```
bool[] bools=new bool[]{true,true,true,false,true,false,..as.};
            
short[] shorts= BitConverter.ToInt16(?,0);
```

I tried the following methods
Each `true` is a `bit`

```
bool[] bools=new bool[]{true,true,true,false,true,false};
List<bool> list=new List<bool>();
list.AddRange(bools);
int ints= bools.Length%16;
for(int i=0;i<16-ints;i++){
   list.Add(false);
}
BitArray bits=new BitArray(list.ToArray());
byte[] bytes= ToByteArray(bits);
short[] shorts=new short[bytes.Length/2];
for(int i=0;i<bytes.Length/2;i++)
shorts[i]= BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes);
```

Comment: So, if bools isn't 16 long, what do you want to do?

Comment: Is the first `bool` in the array the left-most bit or the right-most bit?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it by hand by shifting bits:

```
    bool[] bools = new bool[]
    {
        true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false,
        true, true, true, false, true, true, true, false,
        true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
        true, true, true, true, 
    };
    var shorts = new List<short>();
    for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i += 16)
    {
        int current = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            current = (current << 1);
            if (i + j < bools.Length && bools[i + j])
            {
                current = (current | 1);
            }
        }
        shorts.Add((short)current);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(shorts[0], 2));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(shorts[1], 2));
```

Should output:

```
"1110101011101110"
"1000000011110000"
```

Another alternative would be to convert the bools to strings with 0/1, and use Convert.ToInt16, i.e. `Convert.ToInt16("1110101011101011", 2)`

I would note that this would be a rather odd thing to do since representing binary data as bools is rather inefficient. It is much more common to represent binary data as byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If the first bool value in the array is the left-most bit, try something like this:

```
bool[] bools = new bool[] { true, true, true, false, true, false, false };
List<short> shorts = new List<short>();
for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
{
    short s = 0;
    if (bools[i] == true)
        s |= (short)(1 << i % 16);
    shorts.Add(s);
}
```

If the first bool value in the array is the right-most bit, reverse the bool array first before the loop.

```
bool[] bools = new bool[] { true, true, true, false, true, false, false };
Array.Reverse(bools);
List<short> shorts = new List<short>();
for (int i = 0; i < bools.Length; i++)
{
    short s = 0;
    if (bools[i] == true)
        s |= (short)(1 << i % 16);
    shorts.Add(s);
}
```

I didn't test the code, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how would you treat these boolean values. If you have at most `16` bools(`true` for `1`, false for `0`),
you can put something like:

```
using System.Linq;

...

short x = unchecked((short)bools.Aggregate(0, (s, a) => s * 2 + (a ? 1 : 0)));
```

if `bools` is of arbitraty length (and you have an *array* of `short`)

```
short[] shorts = bools
  .Select((b, index) => new {b, index})
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 16, pair => pair.b ? 1 : 0)
  .Select(group => unchecked((short)group.Aggregate((s, a) => s * 2 + a)))
  .ToArray();
```

If you want to stick to `BitConverter` logic you have to work with `byte[]`:

```
short[] shorts = bools
  .Select((b, index) => new {b, index})
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 8, pair => pair.b ? 1 : 0)
  .Select(group => (byte)group.Aggregate((s, a) => s * 2 + a))
  .Select((b, index) => new {b, index})
  .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / 2, pair => pair.b)
  .Select(group => group.ToArray())
  .Select(array => array.Length == 2 
     ? BitConverter.ToInt16(array)
     : BitConverter.ToInt16(array.Concat(new byte[1]).ToArray()))
 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused as to why you are going for 16 bits of chunks while wanting to use a float/ Single, anyway presuming you actually are going for 16 bit values, you could come about to what you ask like the suggestion below.

Please feel free to clarify the usage of Singles as it relates to data and point out what i missed :)

```
[Fact]
public void ContinuousWordsTest()
{
    var rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    var length = rnd.Next(32, 4000);
    var boolsList = new List<bool>(length);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        boolsList.Add(Convert.ToBoolean(rnd.Next(0, 2)));
    }

    int idx = 0;
    var multipliers = new ushort[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096,  8192, 16384, 32768};
    var resultsList = new List<Single>();  // is in .net same as float
    ushort buildNumber = 0;
    foreach(var boolish in boolsList)
    {
        if(boolish)
            buildNumber |= multipliers[idx];

        idx++;
        if (idx % 16 == 0)
        {
            idx = 0;
            resultsList.Add(Convert.ToSingle(buildNumber));
            buildNumber = 0;
        }
    }
    Assert.NotEmpty(resultsList);
    //TODO: Consider if we don't actually want to use an integral numeric type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types
    //TODO: Consider why using a float at all, if you have 2 bytes and why else be going for 16 bit lumps, hence you really cannot get such big a number anyway
    
}-
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list of bools 16 at a time and convert each group of 16 into a ushort. Linq makes this pretty easy. For people uncomfortable with bit-twiddling this doesn't require any.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bools = Enumerable.Repeat(true, 100).ToArray(); //should produce 6 ushort.Max-1 and have 4 bits leftover = 15
        
        var ushorts = new List<ushort>();
        var tempInt = new int[1];
        foreach (var sixteenbools in bools.Select((x, i) => new {Group = i/16, Value =x})
                                          .GroupBy(item => item.Group, g => g.Value)
                                          .Select(g => g.Where(x => true)))
        {
            var bitVector = new BitArray(sixteenbools.ToArray());
            bitVector.CopyTo(tempInt,0);
            ushorts.Add((ushort)tempInt[0]);
            
            Console.WriteLine(tempInt[0]);
        } 
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: [sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEEps8)